# Preview the data flowing through the bonobo-etl ETL graph

Tags: bonobo-etl

The Pentaho Data Data Integration has a nice feature allowing you to preview the data output for each transformation step.

Is there a similar feature in bonobo-etl?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such feature.

If we consider that all transformations falls in two families, the transformations with side-effects (write a file, insert in database, post on the network ...) and those without, only the later are safe to "preview".

For transformations with side-effect there is no safe way to create a generic "preview". The developper actually needs to know what the transformation does to be able to imagine what the preview would be, and create some "mock" version for the preview.

For transformations without side-effects though, it's kind of easy. Transformations are python callables, and thus you can just pass the input and look at the output.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I thought I saw a glimpse of something like that in your Euopython presentation, but I can't find it right now.